# How to sanitize all body params including complex object

Tags: node.js, express, sanitize

I saw examples to sanitize a single property

How can I sanitize all body?

In asp.net mvc/webapi all model sanitize automatically.

I want to do this:

```js
req.body = req.sanitize(req.body);
```

and not this:

```js
req.body.a = req.sanitize(req.body.a);
req.body.b = req.sanitize(req.body.b);
req.body.c = req.sanitize(req.body.c);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: i added example

Comment: And what does "sanitize" mean to you?

Comment: sanitize remove suspicious code, its expressValidator function

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what sanitize is doing. However, assuming it is just a normal function, you could do something like this:

```js
req.body = req.body.map(sub => req.sanitize(sub));
```